# Using If Statement in VBA to perform Copy and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help in writing a code in VBA. I thought I had a pretty good grasp of it, but apparently not.

I have two worksheets in a workbook, "Data" and "Results". "Data" has contents in E2 through E580, but this could change +/-. "Results" has contents in C10 that needs to be copied into D2 and down the column, but only if there is contents in "Data" (E2:E580). Here is what I have so far:

```
Worksheets("Data").If (Range("E2:E580") = " ", Copy.Worksheets("Results").Range("C10") AND Paste.Worksheets("Data").Range("D2:D580"), False)
```

**Getting Compile Error:
Expected =**

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest recording a macro and seeing what that code looks like.

Comment: read this to understand the use of If then else: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/752y8abs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copy_data()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
  If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
     Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 4) = Sheets("Results").Range("C10")
  Else
     Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 4) = ""
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Explanation: Loop through column E in "Data" down to the last entry and copy content from C10 in "Results" into column D if there is a value in the corresponding cell in "Data". If there is no value enter an empty string